# Не удаляется запись wordpress из дополнительной таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Дополнительно в БД создана таблица "Event", столбец event_id совпадает с id записи wordpress. Нужно чтобы при удалении записи, стандартным способом в Админ панели, удалялась и запись в таблице Event.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpdocs_codex_init' );
function wpdocs_codex_init() {
    add_action( 'delete_post', 'wpdocs_codex_sync', 1, 1 );
}
 
function wpdocs_codex_sync() {
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $query2 = $wpdb->prepare( 'DELETE FROM Event WHERE event_id = %d', $post->ID );
    $wpdb->query( $query2 );
}
```

Запрос который нашёл в интернете и попытался переделать под себя, не работает.

Comment: Потому что `$post_id` Вы должны принимать в качетсве первого параметра в функции `wpdocs_codex_sync()` и потом уже подавать вторым параметром в `$wpdb->prepare()`.

Comment: *Нужно чтобы при удалении записи, стандартным способом в Админ панели, удалялась и запись в таблице Event.* На уровне SQL это делает (автоматически) правило внешнего ключа с прописанным каскадным удалением. При этом никакого дополнительного кода не требуется.